Maven Deploy Results in 301 Failure
I've built up a dependency in java.  Nothing special, just some utility functionality.  I can deploy it locally, and use it with no problem, but I'd like to deploy it to maven central.  I set up my POM using GitHub, and I cannot seem to get it to deploy to my repository.  I have the settings.xml file located in the .m2 directory and it is shown below.
I have GPG installed, and have a key generated with it as well.
My end goal is I want to build/deploy this with proper signatures/hashes/etc to eventually deploy to central.
Can anyone see what I've done wrong here?  I feel like it's some minor detail, but I'm really not sure
OS: Mac OSX
Maven Version:  Tried 3.9.2 and 3.8.8 with the same result
IDE:  VS Code
I run men clean deploy, and get the following:
[INFO] --- deploy:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ MyArtifactName ---
Uploading to github: https://www.github.com/MyUserName/MyRepoName/io/github/MyUserName/MyArtifactName/1.0/MyArtifactName-1.0.jar
Uploading to github: https://www.github.com/MyUserName/MyRepoName/io/github/MyUserName/MyArtifactName/1.0/MyArtifactName-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  19.692 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-08T00:10:46-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project MyArtifactName: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact io.github.MyUserName:MyArtifactName:jar:1.0 from/to github (https://www.github.com/MyUserName/MyRepoName): status code: 301, reason phrase: Moved Permanently (301) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 

I have searched in many places, hit YouTube, google, etc looking for some result.  I really think this has something to do with GitHub authentication, or maybe something in my settings file, but I'm not sure.
I have tried several different configuration with the POM file, and none seem to work.  Again, if I deploy locally, or install locally, it's all fine.  Everything works as expected.
Placeholder info
MyUserName
MyRepoName
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>MyUserName</username>
            <password>GITHUB_CLASSIC_TOKEN_GENERATED</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>github</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>github</id>
                    <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/MyUserName/MyRepoName</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>

My POM has this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.namespace.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyArtifactName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>Generic Description</description>
    <url>http://www.github.com/MyUserName</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>My Name</name>
            <email>my.email@gmail.com</email>
            <organization>My Name</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.github.com/MyUserName</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/MyUserName/MyRepoName.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://github.com:MyUserName/MyUserName.git</developerConnection>
        <url>http://github.com/MyUserName/MyRepoName/tree/main</url>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>GitHub Packages</name>
            <url>https://www.github.com/MyUserName/MyRepoName</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>GitHub Packages</name>
            <url>https://www.github.com/MyUserName/MyRepoName</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <!-- github server corresponds to entry in ~/.m2/settings.xml -->
        <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <!-- Most of these are auto generated add ons -->
    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>

                <!-- additions from SonaType articles -->
                <!-- Distribution Management and Authentication -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.7</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>github</serverId>
                        <nexusUrl>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                        <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Javadoc and Sources Attachments -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- GPG Signed Components -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>


please upgrade all of your plugin to most recent version https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Tried this with no change other than a permissions issue. I have contacted support to see if I’m missing some permission on an account somewhere and will come back here once I have a full solution.

Well, I did some more digging and found a manual way to do this.
I took the following steps:
compiled and installed my code:
man compile

mvn install

Generated my Javadoc:
mvn javadoc:jar

Generated my Sources:
mvn sources:jar

Then I had to sign all my files:
gpg -ab project-javadoc.jar
gpg -ab project-sources.jar
gpg -ab project.jar
gpg -ab project.pom

Then I had to create checksums:
md5 -r project-javadoc.jar > project-javadoc.jar.md5
md5 -r project-sources.jar > project-sources.jar.md5
md5 -r project.jar > project.jar.md5
md5 -r project.pom > project.pom.md5
shasum project-javadoc.jar > project-javadoc.jar.sha1
shasum project-sources.jar > project-sources.jar.sha1
shasum project.jar > project.jar.sha1
shasum project.pom > project.pom.sha1

Then I edited the generated files to remove the file names, and they just contained the sums.
Then I set up a project structure in the same design as my coordinates.  IE - if you project is this:
<groupId>io.github.someUserName</groupId>
<artifactId>someProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1</version>

Your folder structure would be
io/github/someUserName/someProject/1.0.1/

Inside this folder, you place all your sources/signed files/etc
Zip it up.
Go to Sonatype, login to your account, upload your zip file.
Once validated, you can publish.  Hours later, it'll be available once the repository updates.
Hope this helps someone along the way.
